# Como agregar varios datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

como puedo agregar varios datetimepickers sin llamar a varias funciones

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
   <head>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

 <script>
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
});
</script>

 </head>

  <body>

<div style='width:40%'>
 <table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>

    </td>

    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>

    </td>

    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>

    </td>

    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>

    </td>

    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>

    </td>

    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>

    </td>

    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>

    </td>

    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>

    </td>

    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

 </table>

 </div>


 </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza la referencia por clase "." en lugar del id "#"

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.date').datetimepicker();
});
</script>
```